# How do I force the router to update the current route in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, ecmascript-6, angular2-routing

I have a home component and a nav panel component in angular 2. When the user clicks logout on the nav panel (sidebar), the current url is correctly reported as "/login" by logging the router to the console. When the user logs in again, the router instance in the navigation panel reports the current route as "/login" when after the user logs in, the router should take them to the home page. As a result, the user can never get past the login screen, and the views and url in the browser are not updated.

So far I have tried the following:

1. Manually clearing the browser's cache and refreshing the page (this seems to fix the issue)
2. Wrapping the router.navigate call in a call to ngZone.run()
3. Clearing Angular 2's template cache in the home component's constructor.

Here are some relevant portions of code:
The method to handle navigation after the user logs in (in login.component.ts)

```
private doAfterLoggedIn() {
    let returnRoute = this.route.snapshot.queryParams["ReturnUrl"] || "/";
    this.toaster.toast({
        title: `Welcome back!`,
        duration: 2000
    });
    this.router.navigate([returnRoute]);
}
```

The route for the Home component:

```
{
    path: '',
    pathMatch: 'full',
    component: HomeComponent,
    resolve: { author: RouteAuthorResolver },
    data: {
        panelsectionName: "home"
    }
},
```

A portion of the logout method in the nav panel component:

```
doLogout() {
    // leave immediately
    this.router.navigate(["/login"]);
}
```

Comment: For starters, what you are trying to do should work. I do this same thing in my `Angular Routing` course on Pluralsight. What is the value of `returnRoute`? Also, you only need `pathMatch` when using redirect, not when navigating to a component.

Comment: Hi Deborah, thanks for your help. I've removed pathMatch from the route with no luck. returnRoute looks like this: "/Projects" in code and like this: "https://localhost:44358/login?ReturnUrl=%2FProjects" in the url.

Comment: @DeborahK I also had a look at your course over the weekend, and I thought that the issue might have been the ordering of the routes, but they're all in a single module as opposed to multiple modules.

Comment: An additional comment: the home component reports the current url as "/" and the nav panel component reports it as "/login", so it seems that the nav panel is taking precedence with regards to the current url.

Comment: Can you put together a plunker demonstrating this issue so we can look at something more concrete?

Comment: Hi @DeborahK, after another day of banging my head against this issue, I've come up with the solution. When I call a separate method in the subscribe method of the login observable, the routing broke, but when I put the call to this.router.navigate(['/path']) in-line in the subscribe callback, it works perfectly. Any ideas as to why this might be the case? I figure you know quite a bit about the internals of the Angular router. I'll post some sample code shortly. Link: https://gist.github.com/andrelashley/4432ed9395556e8f46841e67ae9cb21a

Comment: Any chance you could change this to a plunker so we could actually run it and try things?

Comment: Sure, will post a link soon as I have some free time.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are bootstrapping component is `HomeComponent` so in the constructor of it check for the login else redirect to the login component.

```
constructor(activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,router:Router){
     if(this.activatedRoute.url !== 'login'){
         if(!userService.geToken()){
               this.router.navigate(["/login"]);
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but I haven't had had any luck with this either. The navigation still does not occur.